# Is it possible to "pack" a .mdd mesh cache animation into the .blend?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, cache, packed-data

I've successfully loaded a mesh cache .mdd file to create an animated mesh. However, if I choose `File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend` the mesh sequence does not seem to get baked in.

Alternatively if I click "Apply" in the Add Modifier > Mesh Cache, I only get the mesh deformation for the selected frame applied to *all* frames of the animation.

How can I pack the .mdd mesh cache animation into the .blend?

Comment: You can pack all sorts of file formats into Blender by adding an Empty-->image, and  selecting the file to be packed.  From there click in the pack-file slot immediately below.  The only formats I've noted that it won't accept are video formats. Their extensions have to be changed to non video, or zip the file, then pack it.  Note that apart from pic files, this method of packing is just that. It saves the file inside the Blend file but has to be recovered (and renamed?) manually.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this means that the data is technically in the .blend but to actually use it I'll have to extract it into a file upon opening? (If so, this is not what I'd like to do. I'd like to pack it the same way textures, environment map images and mesh assets can be packed).

Comment: Unfortunately, this would possibly be the case with the file type you're trying to embed.  It was suggested as a next-best solution, handy for keeping necessary components together, not scattered about the computer or even getting lost.